# Select rows when related field does not include any relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return all clients from orders table only when they haven't made any order that contains element in ('type 1', 'type 2').

that means the list should only bring the clients that never made an order containing type1 or type2.
(an orderitem can have several elements, and a client can have several orders)

I'm trying with the following

```
Select client
From Orders o 
left join orderItems oi On oi.id = o.id
Where Not Exists
( 
    Select * from orderItems 
    Where oi.element in ('type 1', 'type 2')
)
```

and below an example table

```
+----+----------+
| id | client   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | client 1 |
+----+----------+
| 2  | client 2 |
+----+----------+
| 3  | client 3 |
+----+----------+
| 4  | client 4 |
+----+----------+

+----+---------+
| id | element |
+----+---------+
| 1  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
| 1  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
| 2  | type 1  |
+----+---------+
| 2  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
| 2  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
| 3  | type 2  |
+----+---------+
| 3  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
| 4  | type 3  |
+----+---------+
```

in this case, the result should be only **client 1 and client 4**  since only them don't have element type 1 or 2.

I also tried:

```
Select client
From Orders o 
left join orderItems oi On oi.id = o.id
group by client
having count(case when oi.element in ('type 1', 'type 2') then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Please give your table definitions. I can't imagine that `orders` and `orderitems` are joined by `id` on both sides. And why do you have that `left join` there, what data are you trying to get from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS` and correlated subquery:

```
Select client
From Orders o 
Where Not Exists(Select * from orderItems oi 
                 Where oi.id = o.id AND oi.element in ('type 1', 'type 2'));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d17f59fe8d1e9c6cbeb0a9333626eca9)**

Comment: this seems to be the solution, however it doesn't work for me when I try to translate it to my real world scenario, I'll keep trying with it, but this seems to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Select client
From Orders
Where id NOT IN (SELECT Distinct id From orderItems 
             Where element in ('type 1', 'type 2'));
```

Comment: Was this helpful?